# Versioning a VS project with Ankhsvn

Tags: svn, version-control, ankhsvn

I am using Ankhsvn for a solo project. I would like to version this project and add a little log tag to specify release notes. Is this possible? I believe this is the tag feature, but it requests a folder to use which doesn't exist on my system (ie not the repository folder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags are used to identify a special revision of a product. In subversion this is typically done by creating a copy of the trunk folder under a tags folder (subversion does not have real support for tags and little support for branches). When you want  specific log messages in you release notes, you can

1. add a special text in the log message
2. add a svn revision property on the revision which contains the desired log item
3. Gather all logs from a special directory (like gather all messages from the last commit in /tags).

I would use the first one, since it is the easiest way to use.